# How to import any Natural Language Processing Library for reference within my Unity project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nlp, opennlp

I want to import an opensource NLP library into my Unity project but no internet resource has worked and I can't figure out the issue but I assume it has to do with version compatibility. My project is quite up to date so I think my Open NLP libararies for C# or not up to date or compatible with Unity. I'm trying to use NLP to analyze text input and classify it into one of several predetermined categories based on the keywords or phrases used.

Some sources I have tried:
Apache OpenNLP: This only had .jar files and I used IKVM to change them to .dll files but to no avail
Stanford.NLP.NET: Simply was never able to find the file
UnityNLP: Ran into general compatibility errors.

All gave general errors rather than anything specific pointing towards incapability.

I always used the correct `using...` in my header but errors in my code was always related to the missing package reference.

I can provide more information if someone tells me I'm crazy and a certain on of these libraries works well in their Unity project, otherwise I'm looking for confirmation of their deprecation and recommendations on OpenSource libraries otherwise I have to go pay for something.

Comment: What did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: @Orifjon usually the .dll file was broken but once again it was a more general error about the dll file not working

Comment: It's not clear to me how you are referencing these dlls. If you installed a nuget package, it should copy dlls to your output folder. It's hard to guess without having more details.